# WiX 3 Custom Action - Function returns without Exception

Tags: exception, wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.6

I've writen a Custom Action in WiX 3.7 and now when i want to connect to a Database (Firebird) somewhere it just returns out of the function, i've debugged now for more then an hour, but could not figure it out where exactly the problem is

```
Database db;
        try
        {
            db = new Database(@"C:\Cedex2\DB\CEDEX.FDB", DatabaseOpenMode.Transact);
            Debuging.Log("step0");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debuging.Log(ex.Message);
        }
        try
        {
            string sqlScript = "";
            Debuging.Log("step1");
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Cedex2\DB\script1.sql"))
            {
                try
                {
                    sqlScript = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debuging.Log(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            Debuging.Log(sqlScript);
            db.Execute(sqlScript);
            Debuging.Log("step2");
            db.Close();
            Debuging.Log("closed");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debuging.Log(ex.Message);
        }
```

The script exists and the DB-File too. Something have to happen before logging("step0"), because this won't end up in my loging-file. if i manually throw an exception before new Database() it will go in the catch and log. What could be wrong? if it would be a compiler-error, why it doesnt end up in my catch?

The Database-File has also no new Windows-Lastmodified date after running through the Custom Action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the fully qualified namespace of your "Database" class?  Are you trying to use Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Database to open a Firebird database?  If so, that class only opens Windows Installer databases.  ( I suspect you are. )

Take a look at:

[Firebird: .NET — Examples of use](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-examples-of-use/)

Comment: yes i do. hmm, havn't thought about this. that would be the reason why my xml-Database specification doesnt work too. But how can i execute a SQL-Script on the firebird database? i mean there must be a way to implement this i think, otherwise i would have a big problem...

Comment: The roll of DTF is to merely be a model for running managed custom actions in a Windows Installer context.  How to connect to a Firebird database would be a different question unrelated to WiX and DTF.  I've posted a link to get you started though.  PS- Please remember to upvote and accept this answer.

Comment: looks like this is the exact thing that i need. Thanks!